# encountering alert("hello world") in http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js/eval/seq

Tags: ajax, jquery

i have around 20 similar blocks. and on clicking each block an ajax call is made to retrieve contents pertaining to that block .
when i go on clicking each block randomly , after around 10 clicks i get an alert message saying "hello world" from the file specified above. the file doesnt exist in my code.

the block itself is generated by ajax call.

so when i researched they said unbinding and binding the call would solve the problem.

so since this is an ajax call generated block i tried

```
$(".hello").die("click").live("click",function(){ //code });
```

but the issue still persists. i keep on encountering the "hello world" message. i even tried giving the die message inside the click function and triggering the click after the function gets executed. but that disables the click functionality all together.

```
$(".hello").live("click",function(){
        $('.hello').die();
        //some code
        $("hello").live("click",function);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ke4CQ/28/

Comment: Perhaps you could show us a jsfiddle of your code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ke4CQ/28/

Comment: I am not too sure of what the issue is still since I can't reproduce it.  Perhaps you could try using "delegate" or updating your jquery to 1.8 and use "on" ?  Just some suggestions, I am still kind of confused with that fiddle how you could be getting " hello world" without some other code rendering that message.  Its not from the jquery library thats for sure.

Comment: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js/eval/seq/1 - inside this line the code alert("hello world" was present.

Comment: I get a 404 when I load that URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is this:  when the JavaScript engine compiles a new piece of code on the fly (eg, by you calling `eval()` or through the Firebug console) it will tag the code with a source URI.  In Firefox, these dynamic URIs have something like "eval/seq/1" at the end.

It's kind of similar to the way Java would handle inner class "Bar" of parent class "Foo": the class name becomes "Foo$Bar".

Comment: i never called eval() in my code. when i went to inspect why this was happening i saw this eval in the firebug console.

Comment: Somewhere there is dynamic code being compiled.  It could be an event handler, script tags, eval, or any other dynamically loaded code.  Looks like an errant debug statement, but we can only guess until you post your full code.

Comment: Have you ever used `alert("hello world")` as a debug statement in your code?  Is it possible your server returns it as part of the AJAX response during testing and you forgot to remove it?

Comment: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js/eval/seq/1 . inside this file the alert statement was present.

Comment: That's not a file.  JavaScript is just using the jQuery filename as a base for the dynamically generated URI, which represents a new dynamic resource for the sneaky alert statement that's hiding somewhere, probably in your own code.  Try searching your project directory for alert statements....

Comment: OK worth a shot... clear your browser cache: `ctrl+shift+del`

Comment: nope tried that long back.i could not find any hello world statements in my code.

Comment: found the issue. the script was inside one of the response. had to debug for 5 hrs to find it.Thanks . You got it right.